# sudo environment

Tags: configuration, sudo, environment-variables

Is there a way to use config files for use with sudo?

For example a .bashrc, .gitconfig, or an emacs init.el

Specifically I wanted to get LSCOLORS in sudo commands.  I know that I can put these variables in the environment.

eg. in .bashrc:

```
export LSCOLORS = ...
alias sudo='sudo -E'
```

then run sudo

```
sudo ...
```

But I am wondering if there is another way to setup defaults for sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define environment variables in the `/etc/environment` file, `sudo` will load them. This way, you don't need to use the `-E` parameter with `sudo`.
Another approach is to avoid `sudo` resetting the environment by commenting out the line `Defaults env_reset` in the `/etc/sudoers` file. In this case you will have sudo preserve the current environment where it is called from. For further options see `man sudoers`.